# Is there a theorem style with slanted headfont?

Tags: formatting, theorems, amsthm, slanted

I would like to create a theorem style with slanted text in heads. What's the way?

I tried with the `thmtools` package by

```
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\textsl]{slantedhead}
\declaretheorem[style=slantedhead]{exercise}
```

But writing then

```
\begin{exercise}

\end{exercise}
```

produces normal font as head.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would help if you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe), which shows the (manually typed) result you want to have by using the `exercise`-environment.

Comment: @DominikusK. Thanks! The result I wish to obtain in the *exercise* environment would be to get *\textsl{Exercise}* as head title.

Comment: Please edit your question and put a MWE into it, so that all the gifted users her can do their magic and try stuff out.

Comment: If you want to use the `amsthm` package, you can use the `\newtheoremstyle` macro and define the head font style to `\slshape` in the 6th argument. See the [`amsthm` documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you are doing wrong is using `\textsl` instead of the switch `\slshape`.  The former requires an argument, whereas the latter affects the subsequent text.  It is this style that `thmtools` is expecting.  Usually it is a good idea to preceed this with `\normalfont`, so that you know which font you are starting from.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont\slshape]{slantedhead}
\declaretheorem[style=slantedhead]{exercise}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
  Something to work on.
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```